# E: The package livenavigator needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: update-manager

When I want to upgrade packages on Ubuntu 14.10 I get the message

```
E: The package livenavigator needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it
```

I didn't find anything about `livenavigator` on the web.

My update-manager seems out of order... I'm stuck!

Answer (score 2):

Finally,
I edited the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file using

```
sudo -H gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and removed the part referring to `livenavigator`. I saved the file, and then I ran

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and I rebooted the PC.

At least, I restored all APT functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such package in the Ubuntu repositories; check [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=livenavigator&searchon=names&suite=utopic&section=all).

Run `apt-cache policy livenavigator` to find out from what repository you installed the software.

Once you know that, investigate further (or add the output to your question so we can take a look at it.)

I don't know what `livenavigator` is or does and I can't find it on the internet. If you don't know what it is, you may as well try to uninstall it. Be careful and read the output before doing so:
`sudo apt-get remove livenavigator`.

Comment: Actually, I didn't install any livenavigator.  I get this from your code: livenavigator:
  Installed: 3.2-15821
  Candidate: 3.2-15821
  Version table:
 *** 3.2-15821 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: The problem I have is that since this error, any use of apt-get generates this message. So I can't use any more apt-get neither the Ubuntu Software center on the desktop. Idon't if the is a link, but I get this error after installing 'vinagre', the descktop remote viewer.

Comment: I don't think this is related to vinagre, as it's not a listed ependency: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/vinagre